# Transparent overlapping toolbar with Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I am trying to make my toolbar transparent and overlapping on Xamarin.Android, but every time I set the toolbar's color to transparent it becomes white and I'm still not able to make it overlap. 
I have done through several stack overflow similar questions, but nothing has worked for me. Here is my style.

```html
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0B6623</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1f3826</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffe135</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  
  <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="background">@color/transparentBlack</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
```

Here is my toolbar's code :

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

I make the status bar translucent using C# code this way :

```
private void MakeStatusBarTranslucent(bool makeTranslucent)
    {
        if (makeTranslucent)
        {
            SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)(SystemUiFlags.LayoutFullscreen | SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var value = new TypedValue())
            {
                if (Theme.ResolveAttribute(Resource.Attribute.colorPrimaryDark, value, true))
                {
                    var color = new Android.Graphics.Color(value.Data);
                    SetStatusBarColor(color);
                }
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            {
                Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concern you need to have a custom renderer for the Navigation page (assuming you are using a ***NavigationPage***) and override its ***OnLayout***  method.

Droid Example:-

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationNoToolbarPage), typeof(CareMe.Droid.Renderer.NavigationNoToolbarPageRenderer))]
namespace CareMe.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class NavigationNoToolbarPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        IPageController PageController => Element as IPageController;
        NavigationNoToolbarPage CustomNavigationPage => Element as NavigationNoToolbarPage;

        public NavigationNoToolbarPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = true;
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            CustomNavigationPage.IgnoreLayoutChange = false;

            var containerHeight = b - t;

            PageController.ContainerArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, Context.FromPixels(r - l), Context.FromPixels(containerHeight));

            for (var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = GetChildAt(i);

                if (child is Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)
                {
                    var temp = child as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
                    temp.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                }

                child.Layout(0, 0, r, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here ***NavigationNoToolbarPage*** is a custom navigation page derived from ***NavigationPage*** class.

```
public class NavigationNoToolbarPage: NavigationPage
    {
        public bool IgnoreLayoutChange { get; set; } = false;

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            if (!IgnoreLayoutChange)
                base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        }

        public NavigationNoToolbarPage(Page page): base(page)
        {

        }
    }
```

References: 
https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

Cheers! 
Eranda.